# Cannot set user email, removeLoginEmails, or addLoginEmails with setAccountInfo

Tags: gigya

I've tried the following:

Sending

```
profile: {
  email: 'new.email@domain.com',
}
```

to `accounts.setAccountInfo`,

Sending

```
addLoginEmails: 'new.email@domain.com'
```

Followed by

```
removeLoginEmails: 'old.email@domain.com'
```

to `accounts.setAccountInfo`.
Nothing seems to work. I've also tried toggling `conflictHandling: saveProfileAndFail` on and off.

The odd thing is that I can freely edit the user's settings in the Gigya console, just not using the REST APIs. Has anyone else experienced this? Any tips? I tried dumping the logs from the network tab when I was using the Gigya console and the payload of their request is almost identical to mine.

Thanks

Comment: Are you passing the API key, Partner secret and the user's UID? Are you calling the proper Data Center, i.e., if you are in EU, you need to call accounts.eu1.gigya.com/... You can see a code example in many common languages here: https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/accounts.setAccountInfo+REST#accounts.setAccountInfoREST-SampleRequests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comment, @Levi.

It turns out that there's a bit of an undocumented requirement here:

I was using exclusively emails which contained a `+` symbol, I was frequently generating new emails to test some business logic, and it turns out that if the `+` symbol is not URI Encoded (to `%2B`), the calls to `addLoginEmails`, and setting `profile.email` would fail, and the `removeLoginEmails` would simply do nothing.

My new payload looks like this:

```
profile: {
  email: 'new.email%2Btest@domain.com',
},
addLoginEmails: 'new.email%2Btest@domain.com',
removeLoginEmails: 'old.email%2Btest@domain.com',
...
```

and everything functions as expected. The emails are also reflected in the Identity Access area of the console, and my request returns 200 OK as expected.

It seems a bit strange that this wasn't documented and I'm waiting for the next unexpected character error.